# (simple) Not sure what this 'as' array exactly means in route resource controllers

Tags: php, laravel, rest, crud

I'm looking through a project and I wasn't sure about the 'as' array in the in the third parameter and what it exactly does. Haven't been able to find much on it in the laravel docs.

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => 'show', 'as' => 'admin']);
```

Comment: here's the documentation for it: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes

Comment: also here a nice explanation: https://daylerees.com/codebright-advanced-routing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'as' used as a Route identifier. Example:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => 'show', 'as' => 'admin']);
```

You can access that link in such way

```
<a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Resource</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'as' helps in creating named routes as:

```
Route::get('user/profile', ['as' => 'profile', function () {
    //
}]);
```

So that instead of `website_url/user/profile` you can access `website_url/profile`